# "MATLAB" Loading a .mat file with function

Tags: matlab, function

I am having issues in setting up a function that uses data from a .mat file in order to perform some operations on it...

I wrote:

`function [] = name_of_this_program()
clc
clear
%load file.mat`

**file.mat** has 3 variables and my program is to load those variables in a main function and then use sub functions to perform operations... I don't know how to set it up....

What do I do here to load the .mat file and how do I start using sub functions with the .mat file for operations such as using a loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are asking, but from the looks of it the data should be loaded immediately in the function workspace upon parsing the .mat file. Their variable names would be the ones you stored in the .mat file when you exported it. Other than that I can't think of anything else other than you are passing the filename of the folder to import as a parameter. If you require anything else please update this question or better yet, clarify it a bit more!

Comment: I'm having issues in loading it correctly... The .mat file has 3 variables and my program is to load those variables in a main function and then use sub functions to perform operations... I don't know how to set it up....

Comment: I fail to understand what you are saying; you don't know the syntax to load a .mat file? If so what is the error you get?

Comment: After those lines of codes I add `load(file.mat')` and it seems like it works but now I don't know how to start a subfunction and to use the variables within **file.mat**

Comment: Please could you post a runnable minimum working example as well as the error(s) you see?

Comment: Generally if the file you want to load is correct you can see it's contents by typing `whos -file filename.mat`; also if you want to load a variable (that already exists) you have to use the following syntax load('filename.mat', 'y') to override the existing variable. Other than that you have to provide more information or at least the error you have.

Comment: It doesn't show an error and the workspace is empty... I write `function [] = name_of_this_program();
clc;
clear;
load(file.mat');`

Comment: @StrugglingCalcStudent Get `keyboard` right after `load(file.mat')` and then run the function. This will hault the execution at the keyboard point, when you can do `whos` to see if the variables from the mat file were loaded or not.

Comment: I just did that and I see the details of the .mat file in the command window... Thank you! But can you provide me a rundown as to how I am supposed to use the data in the .mat file with subfunctions? For instance like using a subfunction and a loop function in order to perform operations...

Comment: @StrugglingCalcStudent What exactly are your `subfunctions`?

Comment: One is to create a subfunction that uses a loop in order to compute number of data within the .mat file

Comment: If those subfunctions use data from the mat-file, just use them after loading?

Comment: So I can now directly write something like `function [Var2] = compute(Var1)` where Var1 came from the .mat file and Var2 is the output?

Comment: Basically, write a script where you load the mat file and then write a  function in a separate file where you use those variables from the mat-file. Thus, you can call that function with the variables from the mat-file inside that script.

Comment: @StrugglingCalcStudent you have to create a function and call it inside the function you loaded that particular mat file and pass those variables inside the sub-function.